Given data points, formulate their relations
Given a dataset with x, y, and f_xy three columns, how can I formulate a hypothesis regarding the relationship between x, y and f_xy?
The data can be replicated by the following python code:
import pandas as pd

data = 
{'x': {0: 0.3745401188473625,
  1: 0.7319939418114051,
  2: 0.1560186404424365,
  3: 0.0580836121681994,
  4: 0.6011150117432088,
  5: 0.0205844942958024,
  6: 0.8324426408004217,
  7: 0.1818249672071006,
  8: 0.3042422429595377,
  9: 0.4319450186421157,
  10: 0.6118528947223795,
  11: 0.2921446485352181,
  12: 0.4560699842170359,
  13: 0.1996737821583597,
  14: 0.5924145688620425,
  15: 0.6075448519014384,
  16: 0.0650515929852795,
  17: 0.9656320330745594,
  18: 0.3046137691733707,
  19: 0.6842330265121569,
  20: 0.1220382348447788,
  21: 0.0343885211152183,
  22: 0.2587799816000169,
  23: 0.3117110760894109,
  24: 0.5467102793432796,
  25: 0.9695846277645586,
  26: 0.9394989415641892,
  27: 0.5978999788110851,
  28: 0.0884925020519195,
  29: 0.045227288910538,
  30: 0.388677289689482,
  31: 0.8287375091519293,
  32: 0.2809345096873807,
  33: 0.1409242249747626,
  34: 0.0745506436797708,
  35: 0.7722447692966574,
  36: 0.0055221171236023,
  37: 0.7068573438476171,
  38: 0.7712703466859457,
  39: 0.3584657285442726,
  40: 0.8631034258755935,
  41: 0.3308980248526492,
  42: 0.3109823217156622,
  43: 0.7296061783380641,
  44: 0.8872127425763265,
  45: 0.1195942459383017,
  46: 0.7607850486168974,
  47: 0.770967179954561,
  48: 0.5227328293819941,
  49: 0.0254191267440951},
 'y': {0: 0.9507143064099162,
  1: 0.5986584841970366,
  2: 0.1559945203362026,
  3: 0.8661761457749352,
  4: 0.7080725777960455,
  5: 0.9699098521619944,
  6: 0.2123391106782761,
  7: 0.1834045098534338,
  8: 0.5247564316322378,
  9: 0.2912291401980419,
  10: 0.1394938606520418,
  11: 0.3663618432936917,
  12: 0.7851759613930136,
  13: 0.5142344384136116,
  14: 0.0464504127199977,
  15: 0.1705241236872915,
  16: 0.9488855372533332,
  17: 0.8083973481164611,
  18: 0.0976721140063838,
  19: 0.4401524937396013,
  20: 0.4951769101112702,
  21: 0.909320402078782,
  22: 0.662522284353982,
  23: 0.5200680211778108,
  24: 0.184854455525527,
  25: 0.7751328233611146,
  26: 0.8948273504276488,
  27: 0.9218742350231168,
  28: 0.1959828624191452,
  29: 0.3253303307632643,
  30: 0.2713490317738959,
  31: 0.3567533266935893,
  32: 0.5426960831582485,
  33: 0.8021969807540397,
  34: 0.9868869366005172,
  35: 0.1987156815341724,
  36: 0.8154614284548342,
  37: 0.7290071680409873,
  38: 0.0740446517340903,
  39: 0.1158690595251297,
  40: 0.6232981268275579,
  41: 0.0635583502860236,
  42: 0.325183322026747,
  43: 0.6375574713552131,
  44: 0.4722149251619493,
  45: 0.713244787222995,
  46: 0.5612771975694962,
  47: 0.4937955963643907,
  48: 0.4275410183585496,
  49: 0.1078914269933044},
 'f_xy': {0: 0.157130801863798,
  1: 0.1713440485863025,
  2: 3.129805110672629,
  3: 0.204050792591901,
  4: 0.1696344532792451,
  5: 0.3507700760080584,
  6: 0.6976759541933626,
  7: 2.6420140332120847,
  8: 0.6010195813501505,
  9: 1.0230332050209543,
  10: 1.2445986467211745,
  11: 1.196766856155742,
  12: 0.1560149760139054,
  13: 0.9482903687042544,
  14: 1.6336636832821407,
  15: 1.1513253320985553,
  16: 0.2340182514559566,
  17: 0.0273325941782971,
  18: 2.632976880968226,
  19: 0.2266532986907281,
  20: 1.16935854022532,
  21: 0.3966214152543048,
  22: 0.4876505603989647,
  23: 0.656928500996059,
  24: 1.0169235000222618,
  25: 0.0241795100124299,
  26: 0.014129531411363,
  27: 0.017154888508862,
  28: 3.1910192671449296,
  29: 2.3823461725425723,
  30: 1.4519917624809175,
  31: 0.3668196629680049,
  32: 0.7050384080679081,
  33: 0.4011237323170427,
  34: 0.0716906504662595,
  35: 0.6570333572025112,
  36: 0.5406866248448107,
  37: 0.3868260229189749,
  38: 0.9660682048266296,
  39: 2.257494106637491,
  40: 0.1340975089516994,
  41: 2.6887050797417227,
  42: 1.385803460277527,
  43: 0.2538626894067123,
  44: 0.2901622850453029,
  45: 0.479476802610729,
  46: 0.3525629145779723,
  47: 0.1171668916298969,
  48: 0.6217526074701243,
  49: 5.13429928758166}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


Some clarification on what fxy​ represents would be helpful. Assuming it's the dependent variable influenced by x and y, there are several methods you could use. One approach is to visually plot the data, for example, x vs. fxy​, y vs. fxy​, and x vs. y to look for trends. Alternatively, you could apply regression analysis to determine the model that best fits the relationships you are exploring.

thanks for the reply.
I am trying to find the type of relations between x, y and f_xy. so linear regression gonna be the 1st step to test the linear relation. wondering any method to test the non-linear relations?

Here are a couple of libraries which you could use for that; scipy.optimize.curve_fit, scipy.interpolate, sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures. You can look up the docs on how to use them. I believe that these methods do assume that there is a non linear relationship and try to fit parameters.

Before you begin creating any plots, it's crucial to understand the key relationships you wish to illustrate. For instance, consider a dataset where $x$ represents the ages of individuals, $y$ represents their weights, and $f_{xy}$ denotes the time taken to run 100 meters. The objective here is to examine how running speed varies with age and weight.
A scatter plot is an effective way to visualize relationships within a dataset, where you could show $x$ and $y$ simultaneously with the size of scatter indicates how fast ($f_{xy}$) the runner is. Below is an example using Python's seaborn library:
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.scatterplot(x='x', y='y', size='f_{xy}', data=data, hue='f_{xy}', palette='viridis', sizes=(20, 200))
plt.title('Scatter Plot of Age, Weight, and 100m Run Time')
plt.show()

Prior to plotting, consider if you need to prepare your data using pandas to convert  (or expand) it into a DataFrame with further information (such as label for columns or axis) if needed.
